TEXT fields not working properly after migrating to hibernate 6.5.2.Final
We have some fields which are of type TEXT
@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String description;

Until hibernate 6.4.9.Final it was working fine
But from hibernate 6.5.2.Final it has broken
alter scripts are getting executed everytime
alter table if exists user_entity 
       alter column description set data type TEXT

hibernate schemamigrator is not able to understand the TEXT field and treating it as VARCHAR and executing the alter script
has someone fixed this issue ? or has a workaround ?

Found the solution for TEXT fields
@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.OTHER)
private String description;

